# Load function and form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm working on a signup page and I need to have 4 different views of that page. To do this, I want to change only the elements in the container.
At the moment I have a form that has to be submitted.
I need to check if all the required inputs of the form are filled and I'd like to change the url when switching from a page to another.

How can I do? At the moment the js is a try, I need to implement the code to check the form and to change the url.

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  $("#continueBtn").click(function() {
    console.log("click");
    $("#signupBody").load("signup2.html #signupBody");
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="innerContainer">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="signup.js"></script>
  <div id="signupHeader" class="hiBorder lowBorderBg headerSize">
    <div class="verticalCenter welcomeText">
      <h1 class="title">Welcome to NotifyMe!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="colorDots"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="signupBody" class="bodySize">
    <div id="signupDescription" class="description">
      <h1>Thanks for joining NotifyMe!</h1>
      <p>Once registered you'll have access to amazing features that will bring your inspection management to a new level!</p>
    </div>
    <form>
      <div id="signupData">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input id="userID" type="text" autofocus required>

        <label>Password</label>
        <input id="passwd" type="password" required>

        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input id="passwdcheck" type="password" required>

        <div id="conditions">
          <p>
            <input id="checkToggle" style="width:auto;" type="checkbox" required name="Terms and Conditions" /> By continuing, you agree to the <a href="">Terms of Service</a> and the <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="signupBtn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" value="Continue" id="continueBtn">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please ensure that your code snippet is actually working: you are referencing a `signup.js` that does not exist.

Comment: Yes it works, when I click I can see the console.log output "click".